How to create an event grid subscription for a system topic in Bicep or Azure Powershell?
I am trying to create two Event Grid Subscriptions to an Azure Function App containing two EventGridTrigger functions, among other functions for an existing Event Grid System Topic of type Microsoft.Communication.CommunicationServices.
I have tried using both Bicep and Azure Powershell to do it and I am getting the error below:
Destination endpoint not found. Resource details: resourceId: /subscriptions/my-subscription-id/resourceGroups/rg-cc-dev/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/my-func/functions/FunctionEmailDeliveryReportReceived. Resource should pre-exist before attempting this operation.

For example, this is the Azure Powershell code I am using to create the event grid system topic subscription:
# get the parent system topic
$systemTopic = Get-AzEventGridSystemTopic -ResourceGroupName my-rg-acs-dev -name egst-acs-dev

# get the function app containing the EventGridTrigger functions
$func = (Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName rg-cc-dev -Name my-func)

# compose the resourceId of one of the EventGridTrigger functions
$funcEmailDelivery = $func.Id + "/functions/FunctionEmailDeliveryReportReceived"

# create an in-memory representation of the event grid azure function event subscription destination object
$func_evdo = New-AzEventGridAzureFunctionEventSubscriptionDestinationObject -MaxEventsPerBatch 1 -PreferredBatchSizeInKilobyte 64 -ResourceId $funcEmailDelivery

# create an array with the single event we need to get events for
$includedEventTypesForEmailDelivery = @(
    'Microsoft.Communication.EmailDeliveryReportReceived'
)

# create the event grid system topic subscription
New-AzEventGridSystemTopicEventSubscription `
    -EventSubscriptionName evgs-acs-email-delivery-dev `
    -ResourceGroupName my-rg-acs-dev `
    -SystemTopicName $systemTopic.Name `
    -Destination $func_evdo `
    -EventDeliverySchema CloudEventSchemaV1_0 `
    -FilterEnableAdvancedFilteringOnArray `
    -FilterIncludedEventType $includedEventTypesForEmailDelivery `
    -RetryPolicyMaxDeliveryAttempt 10 `
    -RetryPolicyEventTimeToLiveInMinute 1440

NOTE: The Azure Function App already exists, it is started and I can see all the functions it contains. I also tested an HttpTrigger function contained in the Azure Function App and it works, i.e. it accepts the request and provides the correct response.
I prefer to create the event grid system topic subscription either declaratively using Bicep or imperatively using Azure Powershell, however nothing works.
Can anyone please shed some light on what is going on?

Does the user (or other form of principal) that you are using to run this deployment have access to the function app?

Thank you for your feedback. Yes, it is has the roles of Contributor and User Access Administrator (needed to make role assignments for other resources).

I think I found the cause of my issue...The Azure Function App is protected by Microsoft Entra ID. Once I removed the Microsoft Entra ID protection and tried to create the Event Grid System Topic Subscriptions, it worked without issues. Mea culpa!


Create an event grid subscription for a system topic in Bicep or Azure Powershell

The access issue seems to be with Microsoft Entra ID protection as you mentioned because of event Grid Subscription is not able to find the specified function within your Azure Function App.

make sure you this not enabled as you mentioned I tried to test the same in my local but using bicep not with PowerShell and I was able to achieve the requirement.
main.bicep:
param location string = 'EastUS'
param functionAppName string = 'vksbb-func'
param systemTopicName string = 'vckgst-acs-dev'
param functionName1 string = 'FunctionEmailDeliveryReportReceived'
param functionName2 string = 'FunctionOther'

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' existing = {
  name: functionAppName
}

resource existingSystemTopic 'Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics@2021-12-01' existing = {
  name: systemTopicName
}

resource eventGridSubscription1 'Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics/eventSubscriptions@2021-12-01' = {
  name: 'evgs-acs-email-delivery-dev'
  parent: existingSystemTopic
  properties: {
    destination: {
      endpointType: 'AzureFunction'
      properties: {
        resourceId: '${functionApp.id}/functions/${functionName1}'
        maxEventsPerBatch: 1
        preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes: 64
      }
    }
    filter: {
      includedEventTypes: [
        'Microsoft.Communication.EmailDeliveryReportReceived'
      ]
      enableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays: true
    }
    retryPolicy: {
      maxDeliveryAttempts: 10
      eventTimeToLiveInMinutes: 1440
    }
    eventDeliverySchema: 'CloudEventSchemaV1_0'
  }
}

resource eventGridSubscription2 'Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics/eventSubscriptions@2021-12-01' = {
  name: 'evgs-acs-other-dev'
  parent: existingSystemTopic
  properties: {
    destination: {
      endpointType: 'AzureFunction'
      properties: {
        resourceId: '${functionApp.id}/functions/${functionName2}'
        maxEventsPerBatch: 1
        preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes: 64
      }
    }
    filter: {
      includedEventTypes: [
        'Microsoft.Communication.OtherEvent'
      ]
      enableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays: true
    }
    retryPolicy: {
      maxDeliveryAttempts: 10
      eventTimeToLiveInMinutes: 1440
    }
    eventDeliverySchema: 'CloudEventSchemaV1_0'
  }
}

output eventGridSubscription1Id string = eventGridSubscription1.id
output eventGridSubscription2Id string = eventGridSubscription2.id

Deployement:

Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?tabs=workforce-configuration
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#managed-identity-types
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventgrid/eventsubscriptions?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Thanks for your response. Like I said, I had already solved my issue using both Powershell and Bicep templates.
